# SolrNet - ServiceLocator.Current throws a null reference exception

Tags: dependency-injection, solr, solrnet, service-locator

I'm setting up my connection to Solr in the Application_Start method in the global.asax through: `Startup.Init<ApartmentDoc>("http://localhost:8080/solr");`

I have a DAO library project that I'm trying to use to make the calls to the Solr server.  The problem is when I try to access the the instance of my solr connection from the library class, I get a null reference exception on ServiceLocator.Current.

```
var solr = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ISolrOperations<ApartmentDoc>>();
```

I'm new to DI and SolrNet, so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Drew

Comment: Either the code where you put `Startup.Init` isn't running, or something in Application_Start is throwing, or you're running the library code in some different context (e.g. a unit test).

Comment: BTW it's always best to pass the `ISolrOperations<T>` instance explicitly instead of relying on ServiceLocator.

Comment: This is an MVC app, without tests, so I don't think I'm running the code out of context.  I have also verified that the startup.init line is being hit.  I'm unclear what you mean by pass the ISolrOperations<T> explicitly.  Do you mean that I pass the instance to the library?

Comment: yup, pass the instance to the library.

Comment: Also, use the sample app for reference. Compare your application with the sample app.

Comment: You were right the first time.  The code was being executed by a webservice that was referenced in the project, so I was running it out of context.  Thanks - Drew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in the comments, it turns out it was running in a different context, unaffected by Application_Start.